# Adding $timestamp to Multiple Ninja Form submissions

Tags: php, ninja-forms

I have managed to add a $timestamp to a single Ninja Form submission, but not sure how to expand the below code so will work on more than one form.

This is the code that works for a single Ninja Form

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Time Stamp
*/
function my_ninja_forms_date_code(){
    //Declare $ninja_forms_processing as a global variable.
    global $ninja_forms_processing;
    //only process this code on the form ID 1
    $form_id = $ninja_forms_processing->get_form_ID();
    if( $form_id == 2 ){
        //sets timestamp variable to current time
        $timestamp = date('G:i:s');
        //Update the hidden field value for the field with an ID of 41 to the
current time.
        $ninja_forms_processing->update_field_value( 41, $timestamp );
    }
}
add_action( 'ninja_forms_process', 'my_ninja_forms_date_code' );
?>
```

I have tried to add an elseif condition for two forms but was not accepted, see code below:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Example Plugin
*/
<?php
function my_ninja_forms_date_code(){
    //Declare $ninja_forms_processing as a global variable.
    global $ninja_forms_processing;
    //only process this code on the form ID 1
    $form_id = $ninja_forms_processing->get_form_ID();

    if( $form_id == 2 ){
        //sets timestamp variable to current time
        $timestamp = date('G:i:s');
        //Update the hidden field value for the field with an ID of 3 to the current time.
        $ninja_forms_processing->update_field_value( 41, $timestamp );
    }
    elseif ( $form_id == 6 ){
        //sets timestamp variable to current time
        $timestamp = date('G:i:s');
        //Update the hidden field value for the field with an ID of 43 to the current time.
        $ninja_forms_processing->update_field_value( 43, $timestamp );
    }
}
add_action( 'ninja_forms_process', 'my_ninja_forms_date_code' );
?>
```

The $form_id refers to the Ninja Form ID no and the 41 in the $ninja_forms_processing->update_field_value( 41, $timestamp ); is taken from the hidden Field id no.

Any suggestions/guidance would be most welcome.

Comment: have you tried to debug your code to see if the code reaches the statements?

Comment: When I run the code with the added elseif statement it goes blank 501 server error works fine without the elsif statement but that only serves one Ninja form. I am trying to expand the code to serve multiple forms, which is where I am have the problems.

Comment: from my point of view there is no error in the code. The only thing remain to check is the logic of the code. Maybe to check if the form_id is really 6 or the hardcoded 43 in the elseif block is a valid number

Comment: I went back to my server and set the php error to on then ran the above code and got the following error. "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in /home/www/adelphiengineering.co.uk/wp-content/plugins/time-stamp/time-stamp.php on line 5"

Comment: can you paste line 5 of the code in the mentioned file?

Comment: The error message was generated from the second snippet of code that I pasted above - I think this is line 5: $form_id = $ninja_forms_processing->get_form_ID();

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are two `<?php` opening tags in the file you mentioned just erase the second one and your code would do just fine without an error.

Comment: Well spotted, feel silly now for not seeing the obvious. Works like a dream now. Thanks very much

Comment: @AndrewPaton Glad to help